# How to return dymanic (key, value) pairs in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to write a function that will return dynamic key,value pairs.

SERVICE:

```js
getContentfulEntries(query: QueryEntries, keyQuery?: QueryFilters[]): Observable<any> {
    const buildQuery = (obj) => {
      const propName = obj.inequality ? obj.key : obj.key + '[ne]';
      const propValue = obj.value.join(', ');
      console.log('test', propName, propValue);
      return { [propName]: propValue  };
    };
      const contentEntries = this.client.getEntries(Object.assign(query, buildQuery(keyQuery)));
    return from(contentEntries).pipe
      (map ((res: any) => res.items));
  }
```

CONTROLLER:

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Setup Environment';
  private entriesSubscription: Subscription;

  queries: QueryEntries = {
    content_type: 'product'
  };
  keyQueries = [
    {
      key: 'sys.type',
      value: ['Entry'],
      inequality: true
    },
    {
      key: 'sys.id',
      value: ['2zqB3mZMaQOm0uIyIAus8w'],
      inequality: true
    }
  ];

  constructor(private contentfulService: ContentfulService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.queries, this.keyQueries);
    this.contentfulService.getContentfulEntries(this.queries, this.keyQueries)
      .subscribe(res => console.log('ContentfulEntries::', res));
  }
}
```

INTERFACE:

```js
export interface QueryFilters {
  key: string;
  value: string;
  minrange?: number;
  maxrange?: number;
  inequality: boolean; /*Need to specify a content_type in order to use this*/
}
```

So in my final controller, in my query I get key:"sys.type" and value:"Entry". But I want it return it "sys.type":"Entry".

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your object like this

```
let propName = keyQuery.key + '[ne]';
let propValue = keyQuery.value;

const obj = { [propName]: propValue };
```

Function code part. I have also done some refactoring with your code

```
getContentfulEntries(query: QueryEntries, keyQuery?: QueryFilters): Observable<any> {

      let propName = keyQuery.key + '[ne]';
      let propValue = keyQuery.value;

      const obj = { [propName]: propValue };

      const contentEntries = this.client.getEntries(Object.assign(query, obj));
      return from(contentEntries).pipe(map ((res: any) => res.items));

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great but now I need to iterate over an array of objects and pass the different key, value pairs to my getContentfulEntries method. I edited my code snippets in the question..